# Dropwizard REST: Get request is being redirected 302 for some reason

Tags: java, web-services, rest, dropwizard, restful-architecture

I built a REST server using Dropwizard following their tutorial [here](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/getting-started.html).
 The server should serve a single service - display Hello world message.

This is the output when I launched it:

> c:\Users\administrator\Eclipse workspaces\Web\DropwizardExample>java
>   -jar target\DropwizardExample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar server src\main\resources\hello-world.yml INFO  [2016-06-15 12:21:45,341]
>
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.log: Logging initialized @1464ms INFO 
>   [2016-06-15 12:21:45,449] io.dropwizard.server.ServerFactory: Starting
>   hello-world INFO  [2016-06-15 12:21:45,459]
>   io.dropwizard.server.SimpleServerFactory: Registering jersey handler
>   with root path prefix: /hello-world INFO  [2016-06-15 12:21:45,477]
>   io.dropwizard.server.SimpleServerFactory: Registering admin handler
>   with root path prefix: /admin INFO  [2016-06-15 12:21:45,522]
>   org.eclipse.jetty.setuid.SetUIDListener: Opened
>   hello-world@17d2e85{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080} INFO  [2016-06-15
>   12:21:45,525] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
>   INFO  [2016-06-15 12:21:46,207]
>   io.dropwizard.jersey.DropwizardResourceConfig: The following paths
>   were found for the configured resources:
>
> ```
> GET     /hello-world (com.HelloWorldResource)
> ```
>
> INFO  [2016-06-15 12:21:46,208]
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: Started
>   i.d.j.MutableServletContextHandler@18f8a80{/hello-world,null,
>   AVAILABLE} INFO  [2016-06-15 12:21:46,214]
>   io.dropwizard.setup.AdminEnvironment: tasks =
>
> ```
> POST    /tasks/log-level (io.dropwizard.servlets.tasks.LogConfigurationTask)
> POST    /tasks/gc (io.dropwizard.servlets.tasks.GarbageCollectionTask)
> ```
>
> INFO  [2016-06-15 12:21:46,219]
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: Started
>   i.d.j.MutableServletContextHandler@1ab9dd6{/admin,null,AVAILA BLE}
>   INFO  [2016-06-15 12:21:46,293]
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector: Started
>   hello-world@17d2e85{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080} INFO  [2016-06-15
>   12:21:46,293] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: Started @2417ms

The yml file is as follows:

```
template: Hello, %s!
defaultName: Stranger

server:
  type: simple
  applicationContextPath: /hello-world
  adminContextPath: /admin
  connector:
    type: http
    port: 8080
```

When I try to go to

> http://localhost:8080/hello-world

On IE or Chrome, it adds another slash at the end of the address and yields:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2016:12:26:48 +0000] "GET /hello-world HTTP/1.1" **302** - "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   Trident/4. 0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)" 3
>
> 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2016:12:26:48 +0000] "GET /hello-world/ HTTP/1.1" **404** 43 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT
>   6.1; WOW64; Trident/
>   4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)" 3

at the console.

If I manually add the slash at the end, it directly gives me 404.

Can you assist please?

Comment: I am a bit guessing, but can you try 2 things. First, try 127.0.0.1:8080 and see what that does. If that doesn't work, change the port to say 7777 and try that instead. I don't use windows but I wonder if there is some special rule for 8080 with windows and redirects..

Comment: @pandaadb neither helped... :(

Comment: I think in that case I will need to see your code to help :)

Comment: @pandaadb I would be happy to send it to you if you allow. What is you email?

Comment: Just update your question with the code you created so that i can reproduce it on my machine

Comment: @pandaadb there are 4-5 classes... If you are ready you can maybe create a temporary email address, like 10minutemail,  and I will send it to there. I wish I could attach a zip file here...

Comment: dushkin if you don't want to update it here, you can maybe push it to github and make a public repo

Answer (score 0):

Well, I understood the problem. 
I added the following to the yml file:

```
server:
  type: simple
  applicationContextPath: /hello-world
  adminContextPath: /admin
  connector:
    type: http
    port: 7777
```

Well, I am not sure I understood completley why, but it appears to be that a simple server is not required here, but the default one. So after removing this segment, I recieved 200 OK.

Comment: All you did was change the port, isn't it?